Expo Go HTTPS-Request doesn't work on android but works on every other OS. (HTTP-Requests are working)
When I change my environment variable from https://XXXX.com to http://37.XX.XXX.XXX:XXXX, my Expo Go app on Android works, but the HTTPS request doesn't.
Versions:

EXPO-Version: 0.18.26
Expo: 51.0.24
react-native: ^0.74.3

try {
  const response = await fetch(
    process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL + "/login/create",
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
      },
    }
  );

  console.log(response);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Fetch request failed with status ${response.status}`);
  }

  const data = await response.json();

  setError("received");
  console.log("Data received:", data);


  // Working with the response
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Fehler beim Abrufen der Daten:", error);
}

I checked the app.json multiple times:
"android": {
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  },
  "package": "XXX",
  "versionCode": 13,
  "permissions": [
    "INTERNET",
    "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
  ]
},

This bug occurs only on Android, including in the build version of the app.

And yes, before you ask, i've checked if the environment variable is defined and yes, it is defined

So it's working now.
My error was, that there was an underscore (_) in my domain name. WTF Android...
